# Get a map inside a map from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch some data from firestore but it's not going my way...
I have a list containing "name, date and objects".
In firestore I have it like "name, date and a list with the object".
The object has a "name, date, a bool" with the struct map in firestore. The date and name are strings. How can I fetch it, I have tried setting it up as map with a map and a list with a map but no success.

How can I fetch it or struct it in android studio?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't describe your data structure and code in words, but instead show them. In the case of the data structure, you can share a screenshot of a document in the Firestore console, and in the case of the code, show the [minimal complete standalone code with which any of us could reproduce the problem you're having](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to look up Streams and Blocs for this kinda stuff. And I could help further with some of your code to guide me.

But the idea below is that we will have some FutureBuilder that will use fetchItems() as a future. In my FirebaseDB there exists a Stores document. I reach through the document's list of items and create an item for each element. Item has a factory initializer that uses a FirebaseDB map.

```
  class Item {
    String name;
    Timestamp date;
    bool isSomething;

    Item({this.name, this.description, this.price, this.quantity});

    factory Item.fromJSON(Map<dynamic, dynamic> item) {
      return Item(name: item["name"], date: item["date"], isSomething: item["isSomething"]);
    }
  }

  Future<List<Item>> fetchItems() async {
    return Firestore.instance.document("Stores").snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      var name = snapshot.data["name"];
      var itemInfo = snapshot.data["items"] as List;
      return itemInfo.map((item) {
        return Item.fromJSON(item);
      }).toList();
    }).single;
  }
```